# Do Dart property result need to cache?

Tags: dart, flutter, micro-optimization

Do I need to cache Dart property result in release flutter VM for the best of the best performance?

It dartpad, cache will improve performance.

```
class Piggybank {
  List<num> moneys = [];
  Piggybank();

  save(num amt) {
    moneys.add(amt);
  }

  num get total {
    print('counting...');
    return moneys.reduce((x, y) => x + y);
  }

  String get whoAmI {
    return total < 10 ? 'poor' : total < 10000 ? 'ok' : 'rich';
  }

  String get uberWhoAmI {
    num _total = total;
    return _total < 10 ? 'poor' : _total < 10000 ? 'ok' : 'rich';
  }
}

void main() {
  var bank = new Piggybank();
  new List<num>.generate(10000, (i) => i + 1.0)..forEach((x) => bank.save(x));
  print('Me? ${bank.whoAmI}');
  print('Me cool? ${bank.uberWhoAmI}');
}
```

Result

```
counting...
counting...
Me? rich
counting...
Me cool? rich
```

Property method are side effect free.

Answer (score 16):

That entirely depends on how expensive the calculation is and how often the result is requested from the property.

Dart has nice syntax for caching if you actually do want to cache

```
  num _total;
  num get total {
    print('counting...');
    return _total ??= moneys.reduce((x, y) => x + y);
  }

  String _whoAmI;
  String get whoAmI =>
    _whoAmI ??= total < 10 ? 'poor' : total < 10000 ? 'ok' : 'rich';


  String _uberWhoAmI;
  String get uberWhoAmI =>
    _uberWhoAmI ??= total < 10 ? 'poor' : _total < 10000 ? 'ok' : 'rich';
```

To reset the cache because some value the result depends on has changed, just set it to `null`

```
  save(num amt) {
    moneys.add(amt);
    _total = null;
    _whoAmI = null;
    _uberWhoAmI = null;
  }
```

and the next time a property is accessed the values will be recalculated.

Comment: So the answer is no? Dart has nice assignment, but still need to invalidate the cache is too much hassle for performance improvement.

Comment: No, there is no "need". It depends on your concrete use case. How often is the result requested, how expensive is the calculation, how much memory does the cache consume, how complicated is invalidation, ....
It also depends on locality, if the compiler or the CPU does it's own optimization anyway in the specific use case. If you work on performance, memoryconsumption, ... critical code, you'd need to benchmark to figure out what works best in your concrete situation.

Comment: `whoAmI` method access `total` _variable_ twice, in doing so invoke the getter method twice. General assumption will be that it invokes once. Why Dart not automatically cache the result, _assuming_ getter method cannot change object state?

Comment: I don't see a reason Dart should cache by default. Most getters just return a value of another field which is inexpensive. Doing it manually for the remaining cases is simple enough.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer what is the name of this assugnment syntax in dart?